# Trying to Find/Replace in PowerPoint using VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am trying to find/replace a number of words/phrases in powerpoint using VBA. The code below gets stuck at "Set ShpTxt = shp.TextFrame.TextRange" with error saying "The specified value is out of range." This happens in the middle of the document, while earlier occurrences of "MONTH XX, 20XX" aren't replaced. Please help!

```
Sub Multi_FindReplace()

Dim sld As Slide
Dim shp As Shape
Dim ShpTxt As TextRange
Dim TmpTxt As TextRange
Dim FindList As Variant
Dim ReplaceList As Variant
Dim x As Long

FindList = Array("MONTH XX, 20XX", "United States", "Mexico")
ReplaceList = Array("September 22, 2020", "USA", "MEX")

 For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides 
   For Each shp In sld.Shapes
    Set ShpTxt = shp.TextFrame.TextRange

    If ShpTxt <> "" Then
      For x = LBound(FindList) To UBound(FindList)

          Set ShpTxt = shp.TextFrame.TextRange

          Set TmpTxt = ShpTxt.Replace( _
           FindWhat:=FindList(x), _
           Replacewhat:=ReplaceList(x), _
           WholeWords:=True)

          Do While Not TmpTxt Is Nothing
            Set ShpTxt = ShpTxt.Characters(TmpTxt.Start + TmpTxt.Length, 
             ShpTxt.Length)
            Set TmpTxt = ShpTxt.Replace( _
             FindWhat:=FindList(x), _
             Replacewhat:=ReplaceList(x), _
             WholeWords:=True)
          Loop

         Next x

        End If

    Next shp

  Next sld

End Sub
```